# Flutter initState() not populating array?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `initState()` to populate an array when the widget is first initialized, I when I print the `length` of the array after it's first populated I can see that it has a length, but why wouldn't it display (I'm mapping it into a List of Widgets in a column), it's acting as if the array is empty.

It **actually works** if I'm using uncomment `setState`, but isn't initState called before build? how would setState help in this case? is even calling setState within `initState` good practice?

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<Patient> recentPatients = [];

  void getRecentPatients() async {
    var patientMapList = await dbGetAllPatients();

    //setState(() {
    recentPatients = patientMapList
        .map(
          (patientMap) => Patient(
            firstName: patientMap['firstName'],
            lastName: patientMap['lastName'],
            age: patientMap['age'],
            sex: patientMap['sex'],
            phoneNumber: patientMap['phoneNumber'],
            registeredOn: patientMap['registeredOn'],
          ),
        )
        .toList();
    // .sublist(recentPatients.length > 5 ? 5 : recentPatients.length);
    //});

    print(recentPatients.length);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getRecentPatients();
  }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
             return Column(
                children: recentPatients
                    .map((patient) => PatientCard(patient))
                    .toList()),
}
```

Comment: You have async operations in the midst of a sync-only method (initState).  This is leading to your confusing behavior.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thank you, using a FutureBuilder was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer some of your questions:

> Is even calling setState within initState good practice?

No. It is not necessary to call it inside the `initState()` lifecycle method since it is **only called once** when the widget is inserted into the widget tree (i.e. when the widget is initialized)

Regarding your problem, one  of the alternatives I feel is to use `PostFrameCallback` as follows:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getRecentPatients());
    super.initState();
  }
```

As per the documentation for `addPostFrameCallback`:

> Post-frame callbacks cannot be unregistered. They are called exactly once.

Reference doc: [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)

Hope that helps